# Can you switch BIOS to HDMI without a screen?

Tags: display, bios, hdmi, vga

I'm rebuilding an old PC and the BIOS was reset to factory settings so now it's trying to connect to a VGA monitor instead of a HDMI monitor. The problem is that the HDMI monitor is the only monitor I have and I don't even have a VGA cable. Because of the new parts I needed (and still need) for the PC I don't have money to buy or rent a cable or a monitor. Is there anyway I can switch them without having an optical connection?

Comment: “ I'm rebuilding an old PC and the BIOS was reset to factory settings so now it's trying to connect to a VGA monitor instead of a HDMI monitor.” - Both HDMI and VGA D-Sub are capable of detecting if a display is attached or not - and I’ve never known any mobo with onboard HDMI+D-Sub that didn’t auto-switch or at least mirror content on both outputs (excepting a faulty HDMI port… which is frustratingly common) - so I’m skeptical that you actually need a VGA monitor. In order to confirm this **please tell us the exact brand and model of the motherboard**.

Comment: Also please confirm that _only_ CPU-built-in or mobo-onboard graphics are available (I.e. there’s no dedicated NVIDIA/AMD/Matrox/S3 GPU card installed either).

Answer (score 1):

In my location (US) you can get VGA cables from eBay or thrift stores for next to nothing.  I just looked on eBay and saw them selling for $1.

Alternatively, you can post in a forum on the internet or in an app on your phone to find someone local area who can let you borrow/have one.

Comment: And what if the monitor doesn't have a VGA port?

Comment: @Dai it's extremely probable that a monitor purchased today does not have a VGA port. I just upgraded and have none - DP, HDMI only.

Comment: @Seiyria It was a joke and a jab at Apple - indeed, I have loads of non-Apple DP-only monitors now (e.g. HP Z27q, which I )

Answer (score 0):

> I'm rebuilding an old PC and the BIOS was reset to factory settings so
> now it's trying to connect to a VGA monitor instead of a HDMI .

BIOS has to recognize the screen. In this case, it is the VGA screen it must recognize. It cannot see the HDMI screen.

So your option is limited to finding (friend or some other way) from whom you can borrow a VGA cable and a screen that will work with the VGA cable.

Comment: I’ve never known a motherboard with a built-in HDMI port to _not work_ for BIOS Setup, even when other ports were available (D-Sub, DVI, HDMI, DP, etc). I accept that _it’s possible_ but I’ve never come across it in my experience. Can you name any mobo models that have HDMI+D-Sub/VGA that only support VGA for BIOS Setup?

Comment: I took "old" to mean the motherboard did not have a built in HDMI port but used an add-on.  My desktop PC (2016) is like that.